# It is possible to attach files by clicking on capybara

Tags: webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm using `capybara`, `cucumber` and `webDriver` to perform file tests

I am doing a study and need to attach a file, however the file `input` does not exist in the `dom`, and it is only created when the button is clicked, currently my code is like this:

HTML

```
<a id="input-id" href="#" onClick="callInput">Attach</a>
```

Script

```
function callInput(){

    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.style.display = "none";
    input.type = "file";
    input.click();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible the only way would be using the `attach_file` block mode

```
attach_file('/file/to/be/attached') do
  click_link('Attach')
end
```

Since you're setting display to 'none' rather than hiding via setting it offscreen or other methods it's possible the make_visible option could make it work if the above doesn't

```
attach_file('/file/to/be/attached', make_visible: true) do
  click_link('Attach')
end
```

If neither of those work then it's not possible for Capybara to work with the way you've implemented file upload on your page.

Note: odds of either working is pretty low because you're never actually attaching the input to the page so events won't get routed anywhere Capybara can detect.